# Firebird 3 do Firebird 2.5 Free-Adhoc UDFs work?

Tags: adhoc, udf, firebird2.5, firebird-3.0

I am currently running an application on Firebird 1.54 and working on an Upgrade to 2.56. As Firebird 3 is released, I would like to directly go to this version but I need the great Free-AdHoc-UDFs as users also have custom statements in their installations that make heavy use of these UDFs. Apart from that, not all of these UDFs are replaceable by new native functions.

Unfortunately these UDFs are officially only available for Firebird 2.5 and I am currently not even able to compile them for all required platforms.

Does anybody have experiences with UDFs from Firebird 2.5 and using them in Firebird 3?

Update: I found out that Firebird 3 supports functions in PSQL, so my first approach will be to replace the udfs by new self written PSQL functions. But I believe the question still is interesting.

Comment: I would expect them to work, because the API used by UDFs should be backwards compatible iirc, however you will need to test this. BTW: Consider if you still need it at all, or if you can make do with the built-in functions and the new PSQL functions in Firebird 3.

Comment: You are right - I had a deeper look into the features added from 1.5 to 3 and found this amazing. I will go for replacing the UDFs by PSQL functions with the same names, so custom code should run well.